# Gridview - FooterTemplate and 2 related dropdownlist

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview with multiple dropdownlist, textboxes on footer template and I wanted to add the values entered to the grid.
However, I have a condition where the second dropdownlist has to be loaded by based on what is selected in the first dropdownlist.

Is this possible? any examples would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this very good Example: [Implementing Cascading DropDownList in ASP.NET GridView](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=221)

And if you want an AJAX based method, take a look at: [Ajax Cascading DropDownList With Database Example in GridView](http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/02/ajax-cascading-dropdownlist-database.html)